# Can I use two <input> addons in Bootstrap input group?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I saw on the bootstrap site that you could use a addon-field so for example € or .00 is placed before and after a amount of money.

But now I wonder if I could do the same but then use the addon field to enter the amount of money afer the .

and if so, how can I do that ?

Roelof

Edit 1 : Here a example of a bootstrap input field : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic. You see a part where the currency is placed , a white area which is a input-field and a area where .00 is placed. I want that part to be a input field also but keep the same layout.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I don't understand what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap doesn't support that. Custom CSS will be required. This is mentioned in the documentation:

> ### [Basic example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)
>
> Place one add-on or button on either side of an input. You may also place one on both sides of an input.
>
> **We do not support multiple add-ons on a single side.**
>
> ***We do not support multiple form-controls in a single input group.***

Comment: pity then I have to think about another way to do this.